# How to start and get output of "service container" in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to run a container that runs a program until it finishes, as a step in Azure DevOps pipeline Job.

From [documentation it looks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/service-containers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) that what's needed is a service container.

My pipeline yaml is:

```
trigger:
- main


resources:
  containers:
    - container: mycontainer
      image:  mycontainer:latest
      endpoint: myregistry      

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest


services:
  syncice: mycontainer

steps:
- script: |
    ls 
    printenv
```

When the container is `docker run` locally the program shows output, but from DevOps Job no output is showing.

- How to start the container and see output in Job?